# Initialize static field in constructor. It's normal?

Tags: c#, static, constructor

```
public class SharedCacheData : ISharedCacheData
{
    private readonly ISharedPetsService mPetsService;
    private static ISharedEmployeeService mSharedEmployeeService;
 public SharedCacheData(ISharedPetsService petsService, ISharedEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
        mPetsService = petsService;
        mSharedEmployeeService = employeeService;
    }

    public static string GetUserFullName(string key)
    {
        Hashtable value = HttpContext.Current.Application[USERFULLNAME_KEY] as Hashtable;
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = new Hashtable();
            HttpContext.Current.Application[USERFULLNAME_KEY] = value;
        }
        if (value.ContainsKey(key))
            return value[key] as string;

        string name = mSharedEmployeeService.FindOneUser(key);
        value[key] = name;
        return name;
    }
```

Whether initialize static field mSharedEmployeeService (service) in constructors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, that's generally a bad idea. Every time you create a new instance, it will be replacing the static variable. That's almost certainly not what you want to do.

I wonder whether *actually* there should be two classes here - one for the pets service and one for the employee service. It's hard to tell from the code presented, but what we've got here really doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: for people reading this in the future: I would add that using a static constructor (as Mark Robinson notes), would be the way to go.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: Not necessarily. Static field initializers may well be enough, without an actual static constructor. It depends on what timing is required.

Answer (score 6):

Initializing it in a static constructor would make more sense:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // Static constructor
    static SimpleClass()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not recommended, and generally bad practice: Now a call to the static method `GetUserFullName()` will cause an Exception if no instance of `SharedCacheData`  has been created beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

static fields are Class members; constructor are for creating instance members.
And initialising static fields in instance ctors is contrary to OOPS philosphy. Certainly you can do that; but this will change the value of static field for every instance created for that type.

To initialise static fields use static initialiser - which is called at class loading, i.e. before any instance members are created - before ant ctor calls.

A 'static constructor' doesn't actually construct an instance. I prefer to call it a static initialiser.

Also static initialisers don't allow an access modifier.

Comment: Static initializer and static constructor are somewhat different. Static constructor is the name in the spec, so I'd encourage you to use it even if you don't like it. Static initializer isn't a spec term that I'm aware of, but could easily be used for a static *field* initializer... but a class with a static constructor and a class just with static field initializers have different timing.

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is ***"static" fields should be initialized inline*** Hope this makes sense.
Below code snippets for the same

```
 namespace staticFieldsInit
{
  public class Foo
  {
    static int  Id;
    static string Name;

    static Foo() // Noncompliant
    {
      Id = 10;
      ResourceManager sm =  new ResourceManager("strings", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
      s = sm.GetString("mystring");
    }
  }
}
```

Better way to write the above code

```
namespace staticFieldsInit
{
  public class Foo
  {
    static int Id =10;
    static string Name = InitString();

    static string InitString()
    {
      ResourceManager sm = new ResourceManager("strings", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
      return sm.GetString("mystring");
    }
  }
}
```